# User input shows value in other data frame column

Tags: python

I am trying to get the value of a corresponding cell in an adjacent column to show it's value after a user puts in a variable.

Example of the data frame:

|  | Price | Cap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2.5 | 8.5032 |
| 1 | 3.0 | 7.1208 |
| 2 | 3.5 | 5.9551 |
| 3 | 4.0 | 4.9444 |
| 4 | 4.5 | 5.2753 |
| 5 | 5.0 | 4.2754 |

Prompt the user for price and have it return the corresponding value in the Cap column.

The problem I am getting are the results are returning Empty DataFrame when I'm expecting a float value from the Cap column.

Example:
Input Price: 3.0
Cap: 7.1208

The data is being pulled from a csv and not created within the code; if that matters.
Cap column has been converted to float data type from string value.
I've tried to leave the Cap column data as a string and the results still fail.
Created Data Frame is labeled pdfrm

```
Example Code:
```

```
    import numpy as np  
    import pandas as pd 

    prices = "/Users/Me/Desktop/file.csv"   

    pdfrm = pd.read_csv(prices)         

    pdfrm.drop(['Column3','Column4','Column5'],axis = 1, inplace = True)        
    pdfrm.fillna(0, inplace = True)                         
    pdfrm.columns.str.replace(' ','')   
    pdfrm.rename(columns={'Column1':'Price', 'Column2':'Cap'}, inplace=True)    
    pdfrm['Cap'] = pdfrm['Cap'].str.replace('%','')             
    pdfrm['Cap'] = pdfrm['Cap'].astype('float') / 100               
    p = input('What is the price:')
    c = (pdfrm.loc[pdfrm['Cap'] == p])
    print('Cap:',c)
```

or

```
    p = input('What is the price:')
    c = (pdfrm.loc[pdfrm['Price'] == p])
    print('Cap:',c)
```

```
Results:
```

```
    What is the price:3.0
    Cap: Empty DataFrame
    Columns: [Price, Cap]
    Index: []
```

What I am looking for is:

```
    What is the price:3.0
    Cap:7.1208
```

I've removed all NaN values and replaced them with 0.00. All white space has been removed from within the data frame.

Overall the data frame is a two column, 39 row data set that will constantly change and I'm not sure if the code I'm running that specifically needs user input would accomplish what I am looking for.

I'm open to all suggestions.

Comment: It would be nice if you added [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or in other words a block of code that one could copy paste and run on for debugging. It should include definition of dataframe, needed imports etc.

Comment: Added the rest of the code as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that `input()` returns `str` type but you compare with `float` like "0.04"==0.04 and it's not equal.

Here's working code with pandas table you provided:

`pandas_file.py`

```
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd 

prices = "data.csv"   
pdfrm = pd.read_csv(prices)           
pdfrm['Price'] = pdfrm['Price'].astype('float') / 100     

# Enter 0.04          
p = float(input('What is the price:'))  # input() return str type so it should be converted to float
#print(type(p)) # To check variable type
c = (pdfrm.loc[pdfrm['Price'] == p])
print('Cap:',c)
```

`data.csv`

```
Price,Cap
2.5,8.5032
3.0,7.1208
3.5,5.9551
4.0,4.9444
4.5,5.2753
5.0,4.2754
```

Also in your code `c = (pdfrm.loc[pdfrm['Cap'] == p])` it should check for `'Price'`

If it doesn't work it might be problem with data processing step (where you remove spaces and extra characters) to check if it's good do `print(pdfrm)` output should look well formmated like this:

```
   Price     Cap
0    2.5  8.5032
1    3.0  7.1208
2    3.5  5.9551
3    4.0  4.9444
4    4.5  5.2753
5    5.0  4.2754
```

Hope it helps